# How can I compile a wrapper that's written in C# so I can use it with my VB.NET application?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, compilation, wrapper

I want to use the wrapper found at https://github.com/suxrobGM/linkedin-api/tree/master/src/LinkedInApi however normally in the docs there is a nuget link I just type in, how do I go about doing it manually so I can add a reference or DLL to my app and just use it from within VB.NET

Is this possible?

Don't laugh at me if it's not possible but I figure seeing as I've successfully used a few C# .NET Wrappers successfully in the past that there surely must be a way someone can teach me?

Comment: It seems that you would benefit from performing some research on _Git_, _GitHub_, and _NuGet_.  Here's a start: [Publish NuGet packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/nuget-org/publish-a-package)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for a wrapper. You can clone the repository so you have the code if you desire and reference the project. I don't see a NuGet package for this project.

If you have cloned the repo, you can add the project to your solution with the VB.Net project

[image]

Add a project reference to the C# project

[image]

[image]

Then from your VB.Net code you can import the namespace

```vb
Imports LinkedIn.Api
```